# Software from Ubuntu Software broken after install

Tags: 18.04, software-center

I got a new install of 18.04, and when I install en app from Ubuntu Software or snap it will not start. If I install the same app from a deb-package it works.
What is going on? Kinda resembles a permissions problem or something...

Please help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a snap package (example: my-snap-package) fails to open after installing it, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap revert my-snap-package 
sudo snap refresh my-snap-package  
setsid my-snap-package
```

If that doesn't work run the following additional command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall snapd
```