# gimp 2.10 wont start on 16.04 -

Tags: snap, gimp

I tried the 6 steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069321/software-from-ubuntu-software-broken-after-install) but I still have same error

syslog now shows what happened executing the 6 steps for 'upgrade' and 'sysid'

```
rob@ ~$ gimp
cannot locate the core snap: No such file or directory
```

gimp/snap info:

```
name:      gimp
summary:   GNU Image Manipulation Program
publisher: snapcrafters
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/issues
license:   unknown
description: |
  Whether you are a graphic designer, photographer, illustrator, or scientist, GIMP provides you
  with sophisticated tools to get your job done. You can further enhance your productivity with GIMP
  thanks to many customization options and 3rd party plugins.
commands:
  - gimp
snap-id:      KDHYbyuzZukmLhiogKiUksByRhXD2gYV
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: today at 17:50 PDT
channels:                      
  stable:    2.10.6 (47) 192MB -
  candidate: ↑                 
  beta:      ↑                 
  edge:      2.10.6 (47) 192MB -
installed:   2.10.6 (47) 192MB -
```

Details and logs  for `snapd`

```
Sep 15 06:53:22 rob-T460s snapd[862]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Sep 15 06:53:22 rob-T460s snapd[862]: 2018/09/15 06:53:22.384058 daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.34.2 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.4.0-135-generic.
Sep 15 06:53:22 rob-T460s systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
Sep 15 06:53:22 rob-T460s snapd[862]: 2018/09/15 06:53:22.389796 stateengine.go:101: state ensure error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52485->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
Sep 15 06:53:22 rob-T460s systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Sep 15 06:54:13 rob-T460s ureadahead[195]: ureadahead:snapd.quirks_KcfVzk: Ignored relative path
Sep 15 06:54:13 rob-T460s ureadahead[195]: ureadahead:snapd.quirks_ee4MnJ: Ignored relative path
Sep 15 06:54:13 rob-T460s ureadahead[195]: ureadahead:snapd.quirks_z0A3K9: Ignored relative path
Sep 15 06:54:13 rob-T460s ureadahead[195]: ureadahead:snapd.quirks_EwkD9l: Ignored relative path
Sep 15 06:54:13 rob-T460s ureadahead[195]: ureadahead:snapd.quirks_uATJUs: Ignored relative path
Sep 15 06:54:13 rob-T460s ureadahead[195]: ureadahead:snapd.quirks_U5RL4n: Ignored relative path
Sep 15 06:55:09 rob-T460s snapd[862]: 2018/09/15 06:55:09.939016 storehelpers.go:398: cannot refresh:
Sep 15 06:55:09 rob-T460s snapd[862]: snap "core18": snap has no updates available
Sep 15 06:55:09 rob-T460s snapd[862]: snap "gimp": snap has no updates available
Sep 15 06:55:37 rob-T460s snapd[862]: 2018/09/15 06:55:37.940190 storehelpers.go:398: cannot refresh:
Sep 15 06:55:37 rob-T460s snapd[862]: snap "core18": snap has no updates available
Sep 15 06:55:37 rob-T460s snapd[862]: snap "gimp": snap has no updates available
```

Comment: resolved with 'install snap core'